# Quality Histogram - Cannot start Decorator

Tags: meshlab

I have a stl and an obj File of an object.
And I want to use the "Compute curvature principal directions". That works also fine. But I need a scale of the colores. And I found a post to use the "Show Face Quality Histogram".
But then I get the following error:
CANNOT START DECORATOR: the layer does not contain face quality

Or is there another way to show a scale of the different colors?

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix the problem?
Sorry I am new in meshlab.

Thanks for helping.

Best
Nick

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLDwX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter *Compute curvature principal directions* store Gaussian or Mean Curvature inside the per-vertex quality, so you have to use the "Show **Vertex** Quality Histogram" and not per-face.